# How to port Angular SPA (using http-server) to Azure WebApp?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure-web-app-service

I've created an Angular 1.6.x application using Visual Studio Code, with bower'ed dependencies. The Angular app talks to a separate ASP.NET MVC REST/API application for data (eventually with [adal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)).

Locally, I'm using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to run the Angular app successfully using `npm start`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "start http://localhost:8080/app/index.html && http-server -a localhost -p 8080"
  },
```

While I've been able to successfully get the Angular source code to my defined App Services on the Azure (verified using the Web App's console option) using the Continuous Delivery mechanism, it's not entirely obvious how the application will start, specifically:

- How does Azure know how to do a "npm start"? Where do I instruct this to happen, if it's not automatic?
- How would I instruct my application to use process.env.PORT, instead of port 8080?

Assuming I get past this initial issue, are there guidelines for http-server usage on Azure? Or are there other recommended ways to serve Angular SPAs?

FWIW, I note that the trying to run 'npm start' from the Azure console results in an 'ELIFECYCLE' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Web App model hosts node.js/Angular apps within IIS, therefore a configured web.config file is required. The magic glue between IIS and node is the iisnode module: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode that allows hosting of node.js applications within IIS.

The web.config file can direct IIS to start the app's app.js (or server.js) file, which would include a reference to process.env.PORT.

A good overall guide for deploying node apps is: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2015/12/01/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-site-into-azure-web-app-to-create-a-website/.

The best guideline and documentation I could find on setting up a web.config is here: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config

Answer (score 0):

As you deploy your app to Azure WebApp, Azure will use IIS to host your app and only ports 80 and 443 are public-facing. So you don't need any other HTTP server to server your web application on Azure.

You can clarify what issue you ran into when you visited your website, so we can help to figure out what's wrong there.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I found this out over the weekend that it was hosted in IIS by working through the 'Azure Node.js Express 4' template in Visual Studio, specifically the need for a properly configured web.config file.